# How to empty div tag filled by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script where a user enters text into an input box and it displays the text in different fonts as they type in a div below (#Output).

My problem is if a user deletes the text in the input box, the div tag that gets populated is left with all the non dynamic data, how can I can I completely empty the div (in this case #Output) when there is nothing in the input.

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#UpdateText").keyup(function(){
        // Getting the current value of textarea
        var currentText = $(this).val();
        // set font variables
        var text = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
        // Setting the font of Div content
            text += "<div>Font-" + i + " : <span id=\"fontResult\" style=\"font-family:Font-" + i + "\">" + currentText + "</span></div>";
        }
        $('#Output').html(text);
    });
    
});
</script>

  <div class="content">
      <label for="UpdateText">Enter the text you would like here, then select your font</label>
    <br />
    <textarea id="UpdateText" rows="1" cols="30" style="resize: none; text-align: center" placeholder="Type the name/word here..."></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="Output"></div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastest without any other change:

```
 $('#Output').html(currentText ? text : "");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#UpdateText").keyup(function() {
    // Getting the current value of textarea
    var currentText = $(this).val();
    // set font variables
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
      // Setting the font of Div content
      text += "<div>Font-" + i + " : <span id=\"fontResult\" style=\"font-family:Font-" + i + "\">" + currentText + "</span></div>";
    }
    $('#Output').html(currentText ? text : "");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <label for="UpdateText">Enter the text you would like here, then select your font</label>
  <br />
  <textarea id="UpdateText" rows="1" cols="30" style="resize: none; text-align: center" placeholder="Type the name/word here..."></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="Output"></div>
  <!-- end .content -->
</div>
```

Updated version to ES6 and not do anything on empty string

```js
$(function() {
  $("#UpdateText").on("input", function() {
    $('#Output').empty();
    // Getting the current value of textarea
    const currentText = $(this).val().trim();
    if (currentText) {
      // set font variables
      const text = [...Array(31).keys()].slice(1)
        .map(i => `<div>Font-${i}: <span id="fontResult" style="font-family:Font-${i}">${currentText}</span></div>`);
      $('#Output').html(text);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <label for="UpdateText">Enter the text you would like here, then select your font</label>
  <br />
  <textarea id="UpdateText" rows="1" cols="30" style="resize: none; text-align: center" placeholder="Type the name/word here..."></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="Output"></div>
  <!-- end .content -->
</div>
```

Comment: though the iteration still kicks in but this is indeed a quick solution, awesome!

Comment: i guess that's how pro does it, neat! [+1]

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I opted for the first solution as I am already using jquery for other things, and it works perfectly thank you

Comment: @dragon_sa The second is also jQuery :) Just the map is ES6 JavaScript - supported by all newer browsers

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try running the snippet below if this is what you are trying to achieve.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#UpdateText").keyup(function(){
        // Always initialize the display
        $('#Output').html('');
        // Getting the current value of textarea
        var currentText = $(this).val();
        // set font variables

        //check if the textbox is empty (removes the leading and trailing spaces) prevents 30 loops of iteration if empty
        if(currentText.trim() != ''){
          var text = "";
          for (i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
          // Setting the font of Div content
              text += "<div>Font-" + i + " : <span id=\"fontResult\" style=\"font-family:Font-" + i + "\">" + currentText + "</span></div>";
          }
          $('#Output').html(text);
        }
        
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div class="content">
      <label for="UpdateText">Enter the text you would like here, then select your font</label>
    <br />
    <textarea id="UpdateText" rows="1" cols="30" style="resize: none; text-align: center" placeholder="Type the name/word here..."></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="Output"></div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
```